# How to push file to a directory in repository

Tags: git

```
 git init
 git add . or git add ['filename']
 git commit -m "My first File"
 git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git
 git pull origin master
 git push origin master
```

I can push file to a repository in Github via the above command. But now I want to push file to a directory inside the repository `yashirq/practice`, where `yashirq` is the repo name and `practice` is the directory name.

Comment: clone that repository to your local, add a file to perticular folder and commit it git will not change your structure. that's it..!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+file+to+directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **clone the repository**, then you can **access to the folder if already exist** and create/modified the file inside the directory, else **if the folder does not exist then you can create them** add the new file.

At the end of this  operation you can execute the classic command to commit and push you modified file:

```
git add . (Or git add -A)

git commit -m "$$commit message$$"

git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Create directry on your desktop

`mkdir practice`

`touch file`

Than do the following

`git add . Or git add -A`

`git commit -m "message"`

`git pull origin master`

`git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repo first;

If the directory already exists; `cd` to that directory and add your file and then follow the same steps as you followed to add the file.

If the directory doesn't exist then create it first using `mkdir` and then and the respective file and follow the same steps as you followed to add the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
git mv {filename} yashirq/practice/{filename}
```

then commit your changes